# Finding the intersection of a plane and a sphere.

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

Given a sphere with the equation of $x^2+y^2+z^2=144$ and the plane $x=5$, find the equation of the resulting intersection.

I know that the intersection will be a circle. I tried to plug x in as five. However, when graphing this online, I realized that this was a cylinder. I am not sure how to limit this region to only the intersection.

Comment: Something seems wrong with your graphing program or how you use it.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I am not sure what you mean. I literally just plugged in the equations and it seems to be a cylinder.

Comment: Plug in $x=5$ to get a circle $y^2+Z^2=119$, located at $x=5$.

Comment: Any equation in 2D is a surface in 3D. $y^2+z^2=R^2$is circle in 2D and cylinder surface in 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Here $y^2+z^2=119$ would indeed be a cylinder, if $x$ can take any value,

but that is not an expression for this intersection, since we know $x=5$,

so the answer is "$y^2+z^2=119$ and $x=5$", which is a circle.

You could make this a messy single equation such as $(y^2+z^2-119)^2 +(x-5)^2=0$ though it would not be particularly informative and not so obviously be a circle

Comment: Is there a better way to do this with parametrics?

Comment: @randomperson You could try something like $(5,\sqrt{119}\cos(t),\sqrt{119}\sin(t))$ - definitely not a cylinder